# Can't upload to Heroku - says precompiling assets failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm not sure what to do, I've tried other stack overflow questions but can't seem to get anything working, this is the error message that I get:

```
/tmp/build_337f9050-d91f-406c-8516-f9be1c18df90/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top
 (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:stark-beyond-9501.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:stark-beyond-9501.git'
```

LOGS:

```
The initial build for the application failed: Shell command '/sbin/runuser -s /bin/sh 52c811d94382ecdf3b000125 -c "exec /usr/bin/runcon 'unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c5,c288' /bin/sh -c \"gear postreceive --init >> /tmp/initial-build.log 2>&1\""' returned an error. rc=255 .Last 10 kB of build output: 2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/Rakefile:7)
 /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/bin/ruby /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
 DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb.
 See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/Rakefile:7) rake aborted! Invalid CSS after "color: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";" (in /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css) (sass):65   
/var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1149:in `expected' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/script/lexer.rb:199:in `expected!' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/script/parser.rb:471:in 
`assert_expr' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/script/parser.rb:49:in `parse' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1022:in `sass_script' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:882:in 
`value!' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:859:in `declaration' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:582:in `block in declaration_or_ruleset' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1123:in 
`call' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1123:in `rethrow' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:592:in `declaration_or_ruleset' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:554:in `block_child' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-
root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:543:in `block_contents' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:535:in `block' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:529:in `ruleset' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:553:in  
`block_child' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:546:in `block_contents' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:82:in `stylesheet' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:27:in `parse' 
/var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/engine.rb:342:in `_to_tree' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.13/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-
root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/compressor.rb:12:in `compress' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-
2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:243:in `block in css_compressor=' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-
root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:193:in `block in evaluate' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in 
`each' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `evaluate' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in 
`new' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in 
`block in build_asset' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-
root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:19:in `block in compile' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:219:in `block in each_logical_path' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:206:in 
`block (2 levels) in each_file' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each_entry' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204:in `block in each_file' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-
root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each_file' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217:in `each_logical_path' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-
root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-
root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>' Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary (See full trace by running task with --trace) rake aborted! Command failed with status (1): [/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/bin/ruby /var/lib...] /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-
root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task' /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile (See full trace by running 
task with --trace) Result: failure Activation status: failure Activation failed for the following gears: 52c811d94382ecdf3b000125 (Error activating gear: Failed to execute: 'control deploy' for /var/lib/openshift/52c811d94382ecdf3b000125/ruby) Deployment completed with status: failure postreceive failed
```

btw this error is from openshift

Comment: yeah i have this but still get the same error

Comment: What Rails version you use? Can you show the log while running with --trace?

Answer (score 2):

[Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline):

> Environment variables are not available to your app at compile time.
>   This means if you need them for your asset compilation, the task may
>   not run properly. Best practice is to re-write your application to not
>   require environment variables at compile time. If you cannot do this,
>   you can use the user-env-compile labs feature, though its use should
>   be avoided.

Try add in **config/application.rb**

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Also you can try enable a labs feature on Heroku

```
heroku labs:enable ENVIRONMENT -a APPNAME
```

Comment: nothing seems to work i put the config line of code into the application.rb file under module, class Application, i also tried the heroku command you gave me but it didnt fix it either, i have no idea what to do

Comment: you can put here your gitignore please? And your gemfile? Use pastebin.com if you want.

Comment: while you put here the gitignore & gemfile please try `rake assets:clean` and push again with `git push heroku master`

Comment: Also you can try with `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, commit the changes and `git push heroku master`with all compiled.

Comment: my goodness, i was able to deploy to heroku but now the app fails to launch and in my logs it says failed to compiled app...im just lost

Comment: Bro we can't help you without the log, screenshot, whatever. If you are using a repository you should not worry

Comment: Ok man, invite me to your repository (Github or Bitbucket) with skozzcraft[at]gmail[dot].com to check correctly the problem I can't understand this log. Of course if you want.